# Heavy-tailed data

Tags: uses-of-open-data

Hi lately I was focused on theoretical modeling of heavy-tailed data. However, I find it hard to collect some classic heavy-tailed data for experiments. I wonder if there is any public and well-known (better if any) dataset confirmed to be heavy-tailed from Kaggle or some labs ?

Answer (score 1):

The types of heavy-tailed distributions ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution#Common_heavy-tailed_distributions)) gives an overview, and I'd start with [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Occurrence_and_applications) or [Log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Occurrence_and_applications). The hard part will be finding just one dataset!

I'd start with Log-normal, and then going to [this page](https://stat.ethz.ch/%7Estahel/lognormal/lnboard/brochure.html), you see sources for this distribution:

[image]

Let's pick one of the easier ones to find: Length of Spoken Words. (Note that written words is not lognormal - [source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0378375886901692).)

And to keep it relevant, there is good structured data for US Presidential (Campaign) speeches. You mentioned Kaggle, so here is one example:

https://www.kaggle.com/alandu20/2016-us-presidential-campaign-texts-and-polls

> Collection of data from the 2016 U.S. Presidential Election Campaign containing:
>
> 1 Transcripts of the three presidential debates, divided into separate Trump and Clinton text files
>
> 2 Transcripts of Trump's 64 speeches delivered after the RNC and Clinton's 35 speeches delivered after the DNC
>
> 3  Transcripts of select speeches delivered by candidates during the primary campaigns
>
> 4  USC Dornsife/LA Times Presidential Election Poll, with daily breakdown by voter groups
>
> 5  Five Thirty Eight Election Poll, containing daily data from numerous pollsters

1, 2 or 3 would work.

---

*For the record, there are MANY ways of collecting heavy-tailed data, and this is just an example of one way to get started...*

---

for fun, quick analysis from 2016 election:

[image]